# Blazor WebAssembly blazor.boot.json.br file returns 404

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

In trying to improve my application's initial load, I am trying to follow the below link, and use the Brotli compressed files. I keep getting a 404 when the application is looking for the
`_framework/blazor.boot.json.br` file. The file is there on the host in the _framework folder.

Any suggestions?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-7.0#compression

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, IIS wasn't configured to send *.br files. I had to add the following to the web server.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <remove fileExtension=".br" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".br" mimeType="application/brotli" />
        </staticContent>       
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Credit here:
https://github.com/abpframework/abp/pull/13772#issuecomment-1324630884